# Creating Delegate methods in a Protocol

Tags: objective-c, delegates, protocols, derived-class

I cannot seem to build my protocol the way I would like and I have narrowed down to a problem with using derived classes.  If I use a cocoa class it seems to work.  Here is what I have...

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MyView.h"

@protocol MyDelegate  
- (void)view:(MyView *)aView didDoSomethingWithString:(NSString *)string;
@end
```

The MyView class is...

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MyView : UIView {  
    NSString *whatever;  
}  
- (void)myMethod;  
@end  

@implementation MyView  
- (void)myMethod {  
 doSomething...  
}  
@end
```

So when I attempt to build I get the error "Expected ')' before 'MyView'".  If I replace the custom class MyView with UIView then the code compiles.  I am hoping someone sees something that I am overlooking.  Any ideas are appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you including your protocol declaration on your declaration and your view declaration on your protocol declaration? I mean, both .h reference each other?

Comment: OH DRATS! Yes I do. I have a circular reference.  Rotten thing snuck up on me.  In the MyView class I have a reference to an id type that implements the protocol.  "id<MyDelegate>"  I didn't even spot it.  THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure MyView.h contains `@interface MyView : UIView`?

Also, instead of importing you can use @class. e.g.

```
@class MyView;
@protocol MyDelegate
- (void)view:(MyView *)aView didDoSomethingWithString:(NSString *)string;
@end
```

Comment: Thanks seppo, this works also.  But I think I'll remove my circular reference.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the @interface and @implementation parts in different files (if you currently have them in the same file). It looks like you have all that in MyView.m, and you're importing MyView.h, which doesn't exist.

Comment: I agree. It would appear that the problem is not a syntactical one, but a missing file issue. I've often found that xcode error can be miss-leading. Sometimes when it doesn't make sense, you just have to go back to basics and check each part.

Comment: Sorry about that.  They are in separate files.  I should have used two code blocks.